# Moor Vs ObjectBox: For Complex Flutter DB

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-moor

For my next flutter project,
Please suggest to me, which will be the best option to implement DB

Moor or ObjectBox

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It mostly depends on the kind of data you'll be working with. Since the data I'm working with is all relational (stored in Postgres on the back-end) I use Moor. It requires some more setup to join and get the correct data together in the app, but the `watch`/`StreamBuilder` capabilities of Moor make it worth it for my use-case. If any data changes in the background, the UI will update accordingly.

If your data exists only within the app or your backend uses a NoSQL solution like Firestore, using NoSQL (Objectbox) to store the objects likely requires much less effort, and is probably preferred. See also [this Moor FAQ remark about Firebase](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/faq/#firebase).

In the end, as with so many questions in computer science, the answer boils down to "it depends".

#### Note

I have worked with Flutter + Moor, I do not have experience with ObjectBox. I have worked with Firestore in combination with a React web app before.